# Merge two arrays, group by one column, and form a single, delimited string from the other column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, grouping

Here is two similar array and I want to join this on requested way. How can I do that.

```
$arr1 = array( 
    array(
        'Class' => 'Class 1',
        'Student' => array('Name one')
    ),
    array(
        'Class' => 'Class 2',
        'Student' => array('Name one')
    ),
);

$arr2 = array( 
    array(
        'Class' => 'Class 1',
        'Student' => array('Name two, Name three')
    ),
    array(
        'Class' => 'Class 2',
        'Student' => array('Name Two, Name Three, Name Four')
    ),
);
```

Desired result:

```
$result = array( 
    array(
        'Class' => 'Class 1',
        'Student' => array('Name one, Name two, Name three')
    ),
    array(
        'Class' => 'Class 2',
        'Student' => array('Name one, Name Two, Name Three, Name Four')
    ),
);
```

Both array contains have same number of rows with the same columns, but column values are different.

Comment: This seem to be specific to some language... Make sure to [edit] post to add language tag.

Comment: I was stuck in this situation before. There is no built-in method to do that. You need to create your method/function to get the done. Try to create some code and then show us your efforts.

Comment: @KabirUddin You have received a fair volume of answers, please review them all and award the green tick to the answer that you prefer.  Achieving question resolution will help future SO readers to quickly identify the correct/best answer without having to read all of the answers on the page.

Answer (score 2):

you may use [**`array_map`**](http://php.net/array_map) in this as following :

```
$arr1 = array(
    array('Class' => 'Class 1','Student' => array('Name one')),
    array('Class' => 'Class 2','Student' => array('Name one')),
);

$arr2 = array( 
    array('Class' => 'Class 1','Student' => array('Name two, Name three')),
    array('Class' => 'Class 2','Student' => array('Name Two, Name Three, Name Four')),
);

$newList = [];
array_map(function($value, $list) use (&$newList) {
    $newList[] = ['Class' => $value['Class'], 'Student' => array_merge($value['Student'], $list['Student'])];
}, $arr1, $arr2);
print_r($newList);
```

this will output :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [Class] => Class 1 
        [Student] => Array ( [0] => Name one [1] => Name two, Name three ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [Class] => Class 2 
        [Student] => Array ( [0] => Name one [1] => Name Two, Name Three, Name Four ) 
    ) 
)
```

live example : https://3v4l.org/nWNZj

---

#### Update

as [@mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) had mentioned , you may want to only concatenate your students array as a strings,

so this would do the trick,

```
$arr1 = array(
    array('Class' => 'Class 1','Student' => array('Name one')),
    array('Class' => 'Class 2','Student' => array('Name one')),
);

$arr2 = array( 
    array('Class' => 'Class 1','Student' => array('Name two, Name three')),
    array('Class' => 'Class 2','Student' => array('Name Two, Name Three, Name Four')),
);

$newList = [];
array_map(function($value, $list) use (&$newList) {
    $newList[] = ['Class' => $value['Class'], 'Student' => array($value['Student'][0] . ', ' . $list['Student'][0])];
}, $arr1, $arr2);
print_r($newList);
```

this will output a concatenated array element as follows:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Class] => Class 1 
        [Student] => Array ( [0] => Name one, Name two, Name three ) 
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [Class] => Class 2 
        [Student] => Array ( [0] => Name one, Name Two, Name Three, Name Four ) 
    ) 
)
```

live sample: https://3v4l.org/JIeDr

Comment: This is not the desired output in the OP.

Comment: @mickmackusa oops, the question is really unclear, does he want to concatenate strings or merge arrays

Comment: Seems clear enough to me, the expected result array is provided.  I will remove my downvote after it is fixed up.

Comment: @mickmackusa did you noticed the typos in the array provided ?

Comment: I only noticed the missing commas after Class values.  What did I miss?

Comment: that's it , because of that i said that maybe he want to deal with it as arrays

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function:

```
function myMerge($arr1, $arr2) {
    // create associative array keyed by class
    foreach (array_merge($arr1, $arr2) as $pair) {
        $class[$pair['Class']][] = $pair['Student'][0];
    }
    // convert that associative array to indexed array with concatenated students string.
    foreach($class as $name => $students) {
        $result[] = ['Class' => $name, 'Student' => [implode(', ', $students)]];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/761428)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another user defined function you can try -

```
function finalArray($array1, $array2){
  $finalArray = []; #Final Array
  foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value) {
    $finalArray[$key1]['Class'] = $value['Class'];
    foreach($value['Student'] as $key2=>$class){
        $ar1 = $array1[$key1]['Student'][$key2]; #Getting every Student Array Index from First Array
        $ar2 = $array2[$key1]['Student'][$key2]; #Getting every Student Array Index from Second Array
        $ar1 = explode(', ', $ar1);    #String to Array
        $ar2 = explode(', ', $ar2);    #String to Array
        $ar3 = array_merge($ar1,$ar2); #Merge Both Array
        $ar3 = array_unique($ar3);     #Getting Unique Array Index from Both Of Them
        $ar3 = implode(', ', $ar3);    #Array To String
        $finalArray[$key1]['Student'][$key2] = $ar3; #Put in FinalArray
    }
  }

  return $finalArray;  #Return final Array
}

$finalArray = finalArray($arr1,$arr2);
```

> **Note :** Above function will work fine for equal `[Student]` Indexed Array

**Output :**

```
Array(
   [0] => Array(
        [Class] => Class 1
        [Student] => Array
            (
                [0] => Name one, Name two, Name three
            )
    )
   [1] => Array(
        [Class] => Class 2
        [Student] => Array
            (
                [0] => Name one, Name Two, Name Three, Name Four
            )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the first array to create and push references into the result array. Then iterate the second array and either append the Student values to pre-existing references, or just push the new Class row into the result array.  This snippet associates rows by `Class` column value, not by row position/index as done in @hassan's answer.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ulAgk))

```
foreach ($arr1 as $row) {
    $ref[$row['Class']] = $row;
    $result[] =& $ref[$row['Class']];
}

foreach ($arr2 as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref[$row['Class']])) {
        $result[] = $row;
    } else {
        $ref[$row['Class']]['Student'][0] .= ", {$row['Student'][0]}";
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Class' => 'Class 1',
    'Student' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Name one, Name two, Name three',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Class' => 'Class 2',
    'Student' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Name one, Name Two, Name Three, Name Four',
    ),
  ),
)
```